# matcher (java.lang.CharSequence) in Pattern cannot be applied to (java.io.BufferedReader)

Tags: java, regex, text, bufferedreader

I'm using Regex to match something in a text and I get each line with BufferedReader.
Then I find the problem I can't solve:

```
    BufferedReader br=null;
    BufferedWriter bw=null;

    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(myRegex);

    try{
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(originTextUrl);
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(targetTextUrl);
        br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String s="";
        while ((s=br.readLine())!=null){

            Matcher m=p.matcher(br);
```

That's matcher (java.lang.CharSequence) in Pattern cannot be applied to (java.io.BufferedReader),I don't know how to solve this.
Thanks for your answering!

Answer (score 2):

Well as it says, you can't apply a `Pattern` to a `BufferedReader` - you have to read data from the reader, and then apply the pattern to that.

In this case, you're already reading the data - but then you're ignoring it! You want:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
```

I'd also strongly encourage you to use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I do ignore it

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this ?

```
Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
```